# NSString returning NULL while doing NSUTF8StringEncoding

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsstring, nsstringencoding

Following is my code

```
NSString *res = [valueArray valueForKey:@"key"];
NSData *newdata=[res dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
res=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:newdata encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
nameTxt.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",res]; // Assigning to textfield
```

this works properly.
But sometimes it returns NULL data, mostly it happens when string contents large data.

Anyone have idea why this is happening?

Comment: Xcode returns `NULL`?  How does it do that?  And what is this code supposed to do other than a seemingly pointless conversion from string -> data -> string?

Comment: in Textfield it shows (null) value sometimes, i don't know why. if you  know then let me know @trojanfoe.

Comment: And what happens if you do `nameTxt.text = [valueArray valueForKey:@"key"];`?

Comment: whether u hitting any service with this code?

Comment: it show me data with unicodes, but for converting unicodes to Emoji i am using this code. @trojanfoe

Comment: when i send to server i used this code
NSData *data = [nameTxt.text dataUsingEncoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
        NSString *str =[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        [req setPostValue:str forKey:@"key"];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSString *res = [valueArray valueForKey:@"key"];
```

That's funny: using a `valueForKey:` on a variable named `...Array`. Rather seems to be a dictionary?

```
NSData *newdata = [res dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
```

creating a raw UTF8 encoded data from a string always works: No need for `allowLossyConversion`.

```
res = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:newdata encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Converting the UTF8 encoded raw data to ASCII does only work if the UTF8 did not contain any characters out of the very restricted ASCII range. Otherwise `nil` is returned.

This seems to be the *only* reason for this obfuscated bit of code: filter out non-ASCII strings. Otherwise the conversion does not make the slightest sense.

Comment: More likely: Code copied from somewhere without any understanding.

Comment: And just by coincidence I found a post where someone did that nonsense with the express purpose of handling Emojis correctly somehow. Which is of course totally pointless.